# scrapy debug Request object

Tags: python, post, scrapy

How to debug a scrapy Request object?

> requestobj= FormRequest.from_response(response, formxpath =form_xpath,callback=self.parse1)

I need to check formdata of requestobj .But I didn't find any documentation for debugging Request object

Comment: A robust way:`import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` after `requestobj=`, so you can jump to the shell and debug it. the `.` and `tab` key will works. Or you can check the source code in `scrapy/http/request/`.

Answer (score 3):

Use some traffic monitoring software , i personally use fiddler. it will help you to check the requests sent from python as well as from browsers

Answer (score 1):

try sending request to:

`http://httpbin.org/`

or

`http://echo.opera.com/`

you will get a response with information your request